# Add xml from kotlin programmatically

Tags: android, xml, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to code an admin section for a food ordering app where they could see the orders that are stored in a firestore database. To do that i have some code to listen the database and get all documents:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class AdminOrders : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_orders)

        val db = Firebase.firestore
        db.collection("Orders").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (e == null && snapshot != null) {
                db.collection("Orders")
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                        for (document in result) {
                            
                            Toast.makeText(this@AdminOrders, document.data["food"].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that to make the ui i would need an xml button that when clicked show the fields of the document for each returned document in the database.

How could i acheive this result in android studio with kotlin ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly do you mean by "Add xml from kotlin programmatically"?

Comment: @AlexMamo i mean that for each document i would have a cardView that displays the order but the problem is that each order doesn't have the same number of ordered food

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***30 minutes of training today could save you months of coding this year.***

*If you're in the beginning stages of your app, this is the most important thing you'll read all day.*

You need to look into the [Android Composable library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial). Most of the Kotlin community has ditched XML in exchange for Composable's function-based UIs.  It makes it **way** easier to connect your data, let alone [build buttons](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material).  You'll never use a `RecyclerView.Adapter` again (hopefully).

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyFirstButton(){
    Button(
    onClick = { /* ... */ },
) {
    // Inner content including an icon and a text label
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Favorite,
        contentDescription = "Favorite",
        modifier = Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSize)
    )
    Spacer(Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing))
    Text("Like")
}
```

*PS: I waited 26 minutes to post this. That's how good it is.*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview) to show orders in a list. Here's a [sample app source](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/RecyclerViewKotlin) in Kotlin.

The [item layout](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/RecyclerViewKotlin/app/src/main/res/layout/flower_item.xml) will have a button. Then set the [Click Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) to show/hide other elements.

Your adapter might look like this:

```kotlin
class OrdersAdapter(private val dataSet: Array<Orders>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView

        init {
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView)
            button = view.findViewById(R.id.button)
        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.order_item, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
        viewHolder.textView.text = dataSet[position].title
        // Set the button handler OnClickListener
        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Show other elements
              }
          });

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
}
```